# Updating List by using for loop

Tags: python, file, loops, for-loop

I have couple of lists and I want to update them..

```
L1=[["Turkey"],["Ireland"],["Ukraine"],["U.S.A"],["Greece"]]
L2=[["Flower"],["Dessert"],["Ice"],["Green"],["Purple"]]
```

and i want to update list according to heroes preferences.. such that..

```
Element "Turkey's" Preference List(ETPL): ['Purple', 'Dessert', 'Red', 'Rouge', 'Blue', 'Mystique', 'Cold', 'Black', 'Fun', 'Storm']
Updated Preference List:[' Purple', 'Dessert', 'Blue', 'Fun', 'Storm']
```

As you see i'm trying to code it.. However i'm wrong somewhere.. My code so far..

```
   common=[]
   for i in ETPL: # looks for the elements of turkey's preference list.
     for k in L1: # the list element which is a list.
        for b in k: 
            for z in b: # the element itself
                if i==z:
                    common.append(i)
   print(common)
```

L2 and ETPL will be compared between themselves.
and then L2 will be sorted according to the preference list.

Can you help me about it? Where i am wrong?

expected output is:

```
Updated Preference List:[' Purple', 'Dessert', 'Blue', 'Fun', 'Storm']
```

Comment: can you please clear up the mess in the format of your question and give variables a proper name / proper python syntax?

Comment: Can you also explain clearly what you want to have as a result.

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote comments to explain what each variable means instead of explaining in the variable name.

Comment: are you sure the `List to be update` is a list of lists?

Comment: unfortunately yes.. i pick the elements randomly from a file and appended to a list.. the result is list of lists..

Comment: Since YOU do it, then I believe you decide the implementation. Then this is a classic [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe what you are trying to achieve. You might be much better off using sets

Comment: BTW, I do hope you collect all the elements from the file into a list and THEN shuffle it

Comment: Please explaing this sentence further `L2 and ETPL will be compared between themselves. and then L2 will be sorted according to the preference list.`

Comment: @Pynchia yes they are from a file.. i want to show them but i cant load these files here.. seeing them maybe helpful for you to understand

Comment: for example [1,2,3,4] is our L2..
and ETPL= [3,5,4,9,8,9,7] first one is highly preferenced and last one is the least preferenced element..

so updated list will be= [3,4,1,2] 
first highly preferenced ones sorted and then less preferenced..

Comment: can you check your email..

Comment: I can't figure out where the values in the updated preference list are coming from. I understand sorting a list based on the order in `ETPL`, but the original list for Turkey was just `Flower`. How does it sort that into `Purple, Dessert, etc.`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, following the example given in your comment

> [1,2,3,4] is our L2 and ETPL=[3,5,4,9,8,9,7] first one is highly
>   preferenced and last one is the least preferenced element.. so updated
>   list will be= [3,4,1,2]

the following code

```
L2 = [1,2,3,4]
ETPL = [3,5,4,9,8,9,7]
op = filter(lambda x: x not in ETPL, L2) # the unique original prefs
tp = filter(lambda x: x in ETPL, L2) # the well known prefs
L2 = sorted(tp, key=lambda x: ETPL.index(x)) # sort them according to their position
L2.extend(op) # add the unique original prefs
print(L2)
```

produces

```
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Or, using

```
L2 = ['Flower', 'Dessert', 'Ice', 'Green', 'Purple']
ETPL = ['Purple', 'Dessert', 'Red', 'Rouge', 'Blue', 'Mystique', 'Cold', 'Black', 'Fun', 'Storm']
```

it produces

```
['Purple', 'Dessert', 'Flower', 'Ice', 'Green']
```

However, if your data is as described in the question (i.e. you have a list of lists), you can use the first element to discriminate

```
L2 = [["Flower"],["Dessert"],["Ice"],["Green"],["Purple"]]
ETPL = ['Purple', 'Dessert', 'Red', 'Rouge', 'Blue', 'Mystique', 'Cold', 'Black', 'Fun', 'Storm']
op = filter(lambda x: x[0] not in ETPL, L2) # the unique original prefs
tp = filter(lambda x: x[0] in ETPL, L2) # the well known prefs
L2 = sorted(tp, key=lambda x: ETPL.index(x[0])) # sort them according to their position
L2.extend(op) # add the unique original prefs
print(L2)
```

producing

```
[['Purple'], ['Dessert'], ['Flower'], ['Ice'], ['Green']]
```